# AWS StepFunctionsLocal StepFunctions test with definition substitutions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have been looking into StepFunctionsLocal (SFL) to test. To get a project bootstrapped, I aws the SAM cli to generate a new project - which comes pre-packed with SFL tests and a make file to run everything.

However, it seems broken out of the box. When running the tests using directions in the README, I get this error:

> InvalidDefinition: An error occurred (InvalidDefinition) when calling the CreateStateMachine operation: Invalid State Machine Definition: ''SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED:
> Value is not a valid resource ARN at /States/Check Stock Value/Resource','SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: Value is not a valid resource ARN at /States/Sell Stock/Resource', 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: Value is not a valid resource ARN at /States/Buy Stock/Resource', 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: Value is not a valid resource ARN at /States/Record Transaction/Resource''

And, indeed, the state machine definition is provided as a file that uses `DefinitionSubstitutions`:

```
{
    "Comment": "A state machine that does mock stock trading.",
    "StartAt": "Check Stock Value",
    "States": {
        "Check Stock Value": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${StockCheckerFunctionArn}", <--
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.TaskFailed"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 15,
                    "MaxAttempts": 5,
                    "BackoffRate": 1.5
                }
            ],
            "Next": "Buy or Sell?"
        },
...
```

The CloudFormation template injects those values

```
StockTradingStateMachine:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine # More info about State Machine Resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-statemachine.html
    Properties:
      DefinitionUri: statemachine/stock_trader.asl.json
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        StockCheckerFunctionArn: !GetAtt StockCheckerFunction.Arn <--
```

the makefile commands to run the test

```
run:
    docker run -p 8083:8083 -d \
    --mount type=bind,readonly,source=$(ROOT_DIR)/statemachine/test/MockConfigFile.json,destination=/home/StepFunctionsLocal/MockConfigFile.json \
    -e SFN_MOCK_CONFIG="/home/StepFunctionsLocal/MockConfigFile.json" \
    amazon/aws-stepfunctions-local

create:
    aws stepfunctions create-state-machine \
        --endpoint-url http://localhost:8083 \
        --definition file://statemachine/stock_trader.asl.json \
        --name "StockTradingLocalTesting" \
        --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/DummyRole" \
        --no-cli-pager \
        --debug

happypathsellstocktest:
    aws stepfunctions start-execution \
        --endpoint http://localhost:8083 \
        --name HappyPathSellStockTest \
        --state-machine arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:StockTradingLocalTesting#HappyPathSellStockTest \
        --no-cli-pager
```

It appears that nothing provides the definition substitutions. I've come up dry when combing through the AWS docs for how to provide those substitutions through the API, maybe I just don't know what to look for. Any clues?

I did make an issue to fix the template: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates/issues/342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `DefinitionSubstitutions` is a feature of the CloudFormation resource and not supported directly in the Step Functions API. You would need to parse and replace the substitution variables in your own code before you call Create State Machine in your test.

Comment: Indeed this is the way that I ended up going; wrote a script to just make the substitutions. The issue linked above also has a suggestion to use `sed`, which works great for a makefile. Though the template still, for now, does not work as described.

Comment: @Justin Callison is this on the roadmap? When can we expect this?

Comment: We are always looking at ways to improve the experience, including the experience of testing workflows. But I can't provide any specifics at this time.